# Executing a final callback depending on the outcome of multiple callback results

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

Im working on some code responsible for printing a document on a number of different printers. For each printer 'sendToPrinter' is called and passed the document, the printer object and an object used by the printer to callback with success or failure. The callback is executed synchronously/asynchronously depending on the printer type, this is a simplified version what I have so far.

```
var x = 0;
var printDocument = function(document, printers) {
    sendToPrinter(document, printers[x], ({
        success: function() {
            x±+;
            if (x < printers.length) {
                printDocument(document, printers);
            }
        },
        failure: function() {
            x++;
            if (x < printers.length) {
                printDocument(document, printers);
            }
        }
    }));
};
```

In addition to this I have two callbacks passed in to the wrapping function, one which is to be called if any of the print jobs are successful, the other if none of them were, this is what Im struggling with.

How can I best track the result of the various print jobs so that after they have all completed I can execute the correct callback?

Comment: `x±+`? The answer seems to be *promises*.

Comment: Use Async.js (works for browser too).https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Is there any timeout for these jobs?

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating it. just loop the printDocument and collect successful responses and introduce timeout, so will not wait too long. If you get number of responses which match the number of printers within the timeout you have your successful printjob done.

Answer (score 1):

Defferds/promises from jquery in combination with 'when' does such synchronization: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

There are also non-jquery solutions available that implement similar solutions.